# Cross Origin Put Request Methods

Tags: ajax, api, proxy, cross-domain, put

What are some successful methods for performing Cross Origin Put requests? I successfully used a Proxy to make a GET request and put it into a Dropdown list as can be seen here >> [Create Dropdown list from API Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862356/create-dropdown-list-from-api-query) >>but have not been able to use the same process in making a PUT Request?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully get a PUT request to work just peachy through the use of the proxy in javascript.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});
```

Once the Proxy was established, I used the chrome extension (now a desktop app) [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to get the PUT HTML code. This was done by first getting the PUT request to work in Postman and then selecting the "code" link (below the "send" button) and selecting "JavaScript Jquery AJAX" from the drop-down. Here is an example of outputted code from Postman.

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://[apiurl].com",
"method": "PUT",
"headers": {
  "content-type": "text/xml",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "postman-token": "[token]"
},
 "data": "<this_is_the_xml_data_youre_sending>"
 }

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response); 
});
```

Once the code is copied from Postman, put the proxy code and Postman javascript into an HTML page and watch the PUT request happen.